# Link de imagem no XML

Tags: html, xml, imagem, xslt

O que eu preciso:

1. Utilizar uma imagem contida num link publicado na internet.
2. Aplicar uma URL localizada dentro do meu banco.

```html
<xsl:for-each select="/Msg/Props/">
<table>
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top" width="200">
<a style="text-decoration: none; width:100%;">
 <xsl:attribute name="href">
  <xsl:value-of select="Prop[@prop_name = 'url']/@val" />
 </xsl:attribute> 
 <img border="0" style="height: 120px; width: 150px;">
  <xsl:attribute name="src">
           <xsl:value-of select="Prop[@prop_name = 'foto']/@val" />
<!--####--> Preciso substibuir a FOTO pela minha URL de imagem publicada na net####  -->
  </xsl:attribute>
 </img>
   
</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Existe alguma forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Você tem algo pronto já, ou está partindo do zero? Código exemplificando é sempre bom.

Comment: Caio, bom dia!   Consegui postar a informação.

Comment: Consegui inserir a url da imagem, mas o link não funcionou: `<tr> <td align="center" valign="middle"> <a style="text-decoration: none; width:100%;"> <xsl:attribute name="href"> <xsl:value-of select="Prop[@prop_name = 'oferta.url']/@val" /> </xsl:attribute> <noXml> <img src="http://namwpm.eccmp.com/wpm/545/img/ver_detalhes.jpg"/> </noXml> </a> </td>
</tr>`

Comment: É preciso conhecer a fonte XML para responder perguntas de XSLT. Ideal é também incluir o XSLT inteiro, pois os caminhos do XPath são referentes ao template. Poste a **fonte XML**, o **XSLT completo** e o **resultado esperado** que poderei lhe mostrar uma ou mais soluções.

Comment: O código que você postou acima está criando: `<tr><td...><a href="VALOR"><noXml><img ...></noXml></a></td></tr>` onde `VALOR` está em `<Msg><Props><Prop prop_name="oferta.url" val="VALOR">...</Prop>...</Props>...</Msg>` . Ou seja, você está selecionando com base em um atributo, para extrair o valor de outro, no mesmo elemento. Se o link não funcionou (e se deveria funcionar) você pode não ter selecionado o elemento correto. Poste o código-fonte.